# How to implement pagination with akka-streams

Tags: akka-stream

I need to process large file by lines and do some heavy work (on 4 core cpu) on every item, I think code correct:

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem("TestSystem")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
import system.dispatcher

val sink = Sink.foreach[String](elem => println("element proceed"))

FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get("file.txt"))
  .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), 64).map(_.utf8String))
  .mapAsync(4)(v =>
    //long op
    Future {
      Thread.sleep(500)
      "updated_" + v
    })
  .to(sink)
  .run()
```

But I want to have output like:

```
100 element proceed
200 element proceed
300 element proceed
357 element proceed. done
```

How to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Flow.grouped`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Flow.html#grouped(n:Int):FlowOps.this.Repr[scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Out]]):

```
val groupSize = 100

val groupedFlow = Flow[String].grouped(groupSize)
```

This Flow can now be injected before or after your `mapAsync`:

```
FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get("file.txt"))
      .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), 64).map(_.utf8String))
      .via(groupedFlow)
  ...
```